# Entire page is printing in IE when using jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, printing

**HTML**

```
<div id="printDiv">
<!-- content Here -->
</div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv()"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
function printDiv()
{
  $("#printDiv").print();
}
```

This is prinitng the specific div when using Mozilla Firefox but when using IE (version 10), it is printing the entire page.

I'm using this jQuery plugin.

```
jQuery.print.js
```

Please help me.

Comment: @Kolink this is the purpose of this plugin, never tested it myself though

Comment: are there any jQuery Print a div plugins for IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without the plugin. I don't know if that plugin is doing something extra. You will have to write a custom js function to print only the div and not the entire page...

**html**

```
<div id="printDiv">
       //content Here
 </div>
```

**js**

```
function customPrint(id) {
     var cont = $('#'+id).html(),
         pageCont = $('body').children();// Updated

     /*Replace the page content with the div content that needs to be printed*/
     $('body').html(cont);

     /*Print function call*/
     window.print();

     /*Place the original page content back*/
     $('body').html(pageCont);
}

customPrint("printDiv");
```

**Update**

```
function customPrint(id) {
         var cont = $('#'+id),
             pageCont = $('body');

         /*Hide the page content*/
         pageCont.hide();
         cont.show();

         /*Print function call*/
         window.print();

         /*Display back the page content*/
         pageCont.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks..but I'm using Content Place Holder..My webpage is inherited by Masterpage...in asp.net

Comment: that doesn't matter...try running this function and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yahooo..its worked..Thanks alot....but after print the page is getting struck until I refresh it..

Comment: getting stuck as is in it hangs are what is happening exactly?

Comment: Actually..I'm using the Jquery Flipbook. That is getting struck not the Menu items....sorry..

Comment: ohh...so instead of replacing the page content you can just hide everything else except the div to be printed. Check the update.

Comment: Sorry. It is prinitng Empty page. Thank u very much for ur help, Abhidev.

Comment: hey corrected the js...check the update http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19025663/revisions